# How to add "Add to cart" in custom module

Tags: php, magento, module, customization, modification-form

Created a simple module to display Promoted product in drop-down menu. Now I would like to have a button "Add to cart/basket" to add this product immediately.
Where is this method or how to do it ?

Comment: To the person who gave me -1, would you like to explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:**

If you are in a block which extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract, you can use this line of code in the block class itself or in the phtml template file of this block to get the add to cart url.

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

**Method 2:**

Pass product object to checkout/cart helper to get the add to cart url.
Then the add to cart link address will be:

```
        $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);//load the product by product id
        $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$skuNum);//or load the product by sku number
        $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->loadByAttribute('sku',$skuNum);//or load the product from a given store id
<a href="<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product);?>">Add to cart</a> //Get the add to cart url
```